# PHP Curl Downloads

Tags: php, curl

I am using Curl to download files from location

```
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=zipfile.tar.gz");
  echo $data;
}

$rt = get_data('http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/13.37/multimedia/umplayer.tar.gz');
```

This does download files , but am not able to open it.Is it mandatory to mention proper Content-Type ? And am using this script for videos , so i tried with Content-Type : Video , but still its not proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER to TRUE and change the content type.

```
<?php

$url = "http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/13.37/multimedia/umplayer.tar.gz";
$opts = array(
  CURLOPT_URL =>$url,
  CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE => "text/xml",
  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: application/x-gzip"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=zipfile.tar.gz");

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: ok that worked , i was looking for video files so i changed it appropriately for video , added video/mp4 for content type it worked. One more Question , if video size increases (say 400MB) it will be using up PHP memory is it ?

Comment: Yes, it will eat up your memory, since you are using `RETURNTRANSFER`, so it is returned into variable that resides in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`

Comment: that might be silly, but I have to ask: Are you printing / echoing  `$rt` anywhere? And are you sure nothing more is printed before / after it?

Comment: Yes after headers i am echoing it